# Dynamic textboxes pushing in arrays implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I need an dynamic array output as following:

```
tableNames = [
    ["string1", "string2"...],
    ["string", "string"...]
];
```

I need to enter value of string from text boxes and each array should be dynamic.
Can anybody help me with  AngularJS code design in order to get such structure?

Comment: **Too broad**, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using ng-repeat and pushing values into an array. but i am not getting expected result.

Comment: Share your implementation code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tableNames is array of array its difficult to ng-repeat every input. So best try array of object.

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);

  app.controller("myCTRL",function($scope){
   $scope.items= [{firstname:'ArunMozhi', lastname:'Varman'},{firstname:'Karikala', lastname:'Cholan'}];
      
      $scope.tableNames = [
    ["string1", "string2"],
    ["string", "string"]
];
 $scope.add = function(){
 $scope.items.unshift({firstname:'', lastname:''}); // you can use push         also
 }

  });
 </script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCTRL">

<br><br>
 <div>
  <form name="addForm" novalidate>
    <button ng-click="add()" ng-disabled="addForm.input.$invalid">Add</button> <br><br>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="item.firstname" ng-required="true">
    <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="item.lastname" ng-required="true">
  <br><br>
      </div>       
  </form>
  
 </div>
 {{items}}
  
  <br><br>
  
  Your Result:-
  
  <div ng-repeat="item in tableNames">
  <form novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item[0]">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item[1]">
   <br><br>
  </form>
  
 </div>
  {{tableNames}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your answer was helping. I found my answer through yours. Thanks a lot

Comment: only thing I needed to add is textboxes are dynamically generated and push values of textboxes in an array.

Comment: yeah you can...

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you. but i found a way to nest array of arrays itself